# Which layout should I use in that case?

Tags: java, android

Which layout should I use for this?
There is a text on the screen. When user touches text it changed to another text but only in a place where touch is. And maybe some animation for this.

Comment: Any layout you wish!

Answer (score 0):

you can use OnClickListener() for the text.

Answer (score 0):

Any layout.. and setOnClickListener in you TextField.

[Linear Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)